# Is this late answer low-quality?

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

I just got a late answer audit on this question: [Exporting a MySQL database with FTP access only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5312925/exporting-a-mysql-database-with-ftp-access-only). I am not sure if you can see the [actual review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/4340803), so I am pasting the answer:

> Yes you can...download phpmyadmin and upload it to your root server. on the url, type www.yourdomain/phpmyadmin to access the database.

First, I believe that using PHPMyAdmin is a correct and probably one of the easiest for the problem. Second, a very similar answer was posted before and was not flagged / removed:

> There is no enough information. If you have web access then one possibility is to use phpMyAdmin.

I believe that the answer that I got is at least of the same quality.

Comment: The fact that there is a second low quality answer on that question is reason to address that other low quality answer, not reason to keep this other low quality answer around.  Also note that questions that have attracted multiple low quality answers (such as this one) is a strong indication that the question should be closed.  In this case, the question is clearly "Too Broad".

Comment: I do not see the other answers during the review process though. Am I supposed to take a look at the actual question to see if there are other low quality answers?

Comment: No, but you're the one that brought up the other answers.  You seem to be making the case that the existence of this other answer implies that the post under review isn't low quality.  I'm saying that that's not true; both are of low quality.  If you didn't notice the other answer when reviewing this one, then you still should have considered this answer of low quality.

Comment: Ah, got it. Personally, I still believe that phpmyadmin is an acceptable answer here, as it would point the user into the right direction and because the installation and usage of PHPMyAdmin is well described and does not have to be discussed here. Sometimes that pointer to a tool is all it takes - in fact the comments show that the user was indeed trying to use PhpMyAdmin later. Anyway - I do understand why you would consider this to be low quality.

Comment: We don't want questions here that just collect answers containing nothing but the name of various tools.  Such answers are considered unacceptably low quality, and and a result questions asking for those types of answers are not acceptable questions.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the clarification.